# How to connect dimmer switch into circuit schematic?

Tags: switches, dc

I need to connect a dimmer switch to a DC circuit for a school project. After some time researching online, I found that this was the circuit symbol for a dimmer switch.

[image]

However, I cannot find posts online which tell me how to connect this to a DC circuit. I hope you can tell me how to attach this to a circuit (in terms of schematics). Thanks

Comment: I have never seen that symbol before in my life, and I've been in the field of electronics for a decade. Also, your standard dimmer switch is AC only. They don't work with DC, not even a little bit.

Comment: that is the symbol that you would place on the control panel, next to the knob ... it's not a schematic diagram symbol

Comment: Oh, thanks everyone for your comments.